# Running Sharepoint 2010 on the minimum system requirements

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was planning on setting up a Microsoft Office Sharepoint 2010 site for evaluation through our technet to see if it was worth purchasing a license for. I was reading the minimum system specs, and [I see this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx):

> Sharepoint RAM: Minimum 8Gb
>   SQL CPU: Minimum 64-bit, eight cores
>   SQL RAM: Minimum 16 GB for medium deployments

Now we all know that you **never** want to run the minimum requirements, but to me that just seems... insane<sub>*1</sub>. Does anyone have any experience running MOSS 2010 on the minimum requirements?

<sub>*1. I know that in 2015 I will come back here and laugh at my shock of 8Gb of RAM, but our application servers only have 24-32Gb of RAM and they're already pretty fully loaded as it is</sub>

Comment: Just a note on the tag moss-2010 tag, SharePoint Server 2010 is not called MOSS. MOSS was strictly 2007.

Comment: @Russell - fair point. What should the correct tag be?

Comment: Good question, I have seen in some MSDN posts referred to as SP2010 (said S-P-Twenty-Ten). Alternatively (but probably too long) SharePoint Server 2010.  In the lookup in edit tags there should be some existing sharepoint 2010 tags.  Other SF posts use sharepoint-2010.

Comment: @Russel - `sharepoint-2010` it is then :)

Comment: :) Now people can find this great question more easily! I am currently trying a dev environment with 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 virtualised with 1.5GB RAM on a 32-bit laptop!

Comment: MOSS 2010 is still used; the product is Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2010; There's also Windows SharePoint Foundation, and only specifying SharePoint it's possible to confuse the two (though unlikely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint runs on a machine with 2 GB RAM. It's not nice, it's not great, it's slow, but it runs. 4 GB is the absolute minimum I would recommend though.

This is for Evaluation/Development.

For Production use, by all means, go with the Sytem Requirements.

Comment: I take it you're using 2008 R2 is the underlying OS?

Comment: Agree on that. I have it running on 2gb - separate SQL Server, though - for testing purposes.

Comment: @Farseeker We use 2008 R2 for Production use. My Development Machine is a x64 Win7 machine with 6 GB of RAM that runs IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2008 R2 and SharePoint. You don't really need Windows 2008 R2, normal 2008 works just as well. For SQL Server 2008, you need some hotfixes though unless you go with 2008 R2 there.

Comment: thanks for the update. It might not be as bad as I thought. I'll try and free up some capacity and see what's what.

Comment: @Farseeker Sure. As said, for Evaluation use you can go really low end. In Production we use 2 Servers with 8 cores (2xQuad Core) and 12 GB RAM each.

Answer (score 2):

Our internal SharePoint 2010 server runs with 2 2.4GHz cores, 2GB of RAM (as of 2 minutes ago: 879MB free physical memory). We run SQL on a separate server which currently has the same specs (but 412MB free RAM). It's quick and plenty good enough for a dozen or so simultaneous users.

If I was running a larger site I'd need to allocate more Processors/RAM; but I keep an eye on it and it's running great.

Answer (score 1):

for evaluation it's "4 GB for developer or evaluation use" from your link but otherwise yeah for the full blown sharepoint install those are reasonable minimums.  It all depends on the size of your deployments.  You've mixed the medium and small deployments together but the link you have gives the correct specs.  The reference architecture mentioned in the doc describes whats meant by medium and small

Comment: Yeah, we have room for evaluation but not deployment. I want to evaluate on the deployment specs. We're somewhere between small and medium according to their planning specs.

Comment: then yeah the minimums realy are the minimums you want to work with.  Below that and various pieces start to get impacted

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that certain service applications are more resource hungry than others, therefore a very basic SharePoint 2010 install with the minimal service apps running would be ok on lower amounts of RAM. As soon as you start turn on things like usage stats or the various office apps then your RAM is going to quickly be consumed.